# celery first in first out not working using python

Tags: python, celery

celery task

```
@app.task()
def single_task(delay):
    """Run task."""
    if delay:
        sleep(10)

    print("ran ...")
    return True
```

terminal 1

```
>>> from settings.celery import single_task
>>> single_task(True)
ran ...
>>>
```

terminal 2

```
>>> from settings.celery import single_task
>>> single_task(False)
ran ...
>>>
```

I am using celery task using django
i am trying to achive to run task on queue so when in first terminal i run it will delay for 10 sec and
immidietly when i call second terminal it will wait for first one to complete i.e. 10 sec

but, now when i call first terminal it takes 10 sec
and when i call second terminal immidietly before 10 sec
it is not waiting first to complete i am expecting it to wait 10 sec until
first task is done as second task there is no delay

i.e. looking for First in first out

Comment: If you want to run tasks one after another, you need to [Chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) them together. The behaviour you described is how it is supposed to work as Celery is there to distribute stuff as much as possible and run tasks concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if fifo is what you are after. You can specify a fifo queue in your broker and having only one worker, which implicitly guarantees that the first task is finished before the second starts. However, first in first out is not the same as having the first task guaranteed to be finished before the second task. It also seems to be a bit counter-intuitive to what to achieve with a messaging infrastructure.

Nevertheless, if you need this functionality, because your tasks depend on each other you might want to look into [workflows, specifically chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html).